# Java Swing JSeparator in Menu incorrectly placed

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, jseparator

I have a problem when i want insert a separator with JSeparator for Java Swing application. In point of fact, I have this problem just when i run my program on Mac, i haven't it on windows or linux. The separator is incorrectly placed, the text is strikethrough. Does anyone know why?

My code :

```
JMenuItem fileItem = new JMenuItem("Close");
KeyStroke ...
fileItem.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL),BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

Screenshot : 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically your code right now shows that you are assuming `JMenuItem` has a default `BorderLayout`, which could be true (but I dont think so).

Though the root problem is you are adding the `JSeparator` to the `JMenuItem` when in fact you should add it to the `JMenu` which contains the various `JMenuItem`s via `JMenu#addSeparator()`. See [How to Use Separators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html) for more.

You should be doing something like:

```
JMenu menu=new JMenu();

JMenuItem item1=new JMenuItem("something 1");
JMenuItem item2=new JMenuItem("something 1");

menu.add(item1);
menu.addSeparator();//lets add that separator
menu.add(item2);
```

giving you something like:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example:

[image]

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar menuBar=new JMenuBar();

        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu menu2 = new JMenu("Else");

        JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("something 1");
        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("something 2");
        JMenuItem item3 = new JMenuItem("else 1");
        JMenuItem item4 = new JMenuItem("else 2");

        menu2.add(item3);
        menu2.addSeparator();//lets add that separator
        menu2.add(item4);

        menu.add(menu2);
        menu.add(item1);
        menu.addSeparator();//lets add that separator
        menu.add(item2);

        menuBar.add(menu);

        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dan While thinking what Layout the JMenuItem would have to allow us to add more items like a `JSeparator` or something and it hit me we do it on the `JMenu` :P

Comment: If i do that , the separator is placed at the beginning of menu. I put it right where I want it between "save as" and "close".

Comment: @Tof hold up ill do an example quick and see whats up

Comment: @David No it's perfect! Sorry I didn't put in the right place between filemenu.add(saveAs) and filemenu.add(fileItemClose). Now it's good! :) 'filemenu.add(saveAs) filemenu.addSeparator() filemenu.add(fileItemClose)'